# Gulp command in Docker container code 139

Tags: node.js, docker, gulp

I have this docker-compose file :

```
  rest-api:
    image: x/rest-api
    build:
      context: ./rest-api/dockerfiles/
      dockerfile: local.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - BUILD_ENV=local
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - ./rest-api:/var/www/rest-api
    user: $UID
  web:
    image: x/web-front
    build:
      context: ./web-front
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/local.Dockerfile
    environment:
      - BUILD_ENV=local
    depends_on:
      - rest-api
    links:
      - rest-api
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
      - "35729:35729"
    volumes:
  - ./web-front:/var/www/web-front
  - ./web-front/logs/:/root/.npm/
    user: $UID
```

and these 2 local.Dockerfile.
rest-api:

```
    FROM node:8-alpine

    RUN mkdir -p /var/www/rest-api/
    WORKDIR /var/www/rest-api/

    EXPOSE 8001

    CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

web-front:

```
 FROM node:8-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/web-front/
WORKDIR /var/www/web-front/

EXPOSE 3001 35729

CMD [ "npm", "run", "local" ]
```

I basically install my all my node_modules from the host, then map the volume to the corresponding folder in the container for both rest-api and web-front. Then I run commands in my package.json from the container.
I experience no issue for the rest-api. On web-front thought, the process exits with  Segmentation fault (core dumped) and error code 139

```
CMD [ "npm", "run", "local" ]
```

runs :

```
"NODE_ENV=local ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js dev --location=local --env=dev --livereload=1",
```

When I run `npm run local` directly on my computer I don'thave this issue.
I already tried a `npm rebuild` with no success
node version on the container is the same as the one on the host.
I  have this debug :

```
    0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'local' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.0
3 info using node@v8.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prelocal', 'local', 'postlocal' ]
5 info lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~prelocal: web-front@0.5.0
6 silly lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~prelocal: no script for prelocal, continuing
7 info lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~local: web-front@0.5.0
8 verbose lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~local: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~local: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/web-front/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
10 verbose lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~local: CWD: /var/www/web-front
11 silly lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~local: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'NODE_ENV=local ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js dev --location=local --env=dev --livereload=1' ]
12 silly lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~local: Returned: code: 139  signal: null
13 info lifecycle web-front@0.5.0~local: Failed to exec local script
14 verbose stack Error: web-front@0.5.0 local: `NODE_ENV=local ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js dev --location=local --env=dev --livereload=1`
14 verbose stack Exit status 139
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:283:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
15 verbose pkgid web-front@0.5.0
16 verbose cwd /var/www/web-front
17 verbose Linux 4.4.0-66-generic
18 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "local"
19 verbose node v8.0.0
20 verbose npm  v5.0.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 139
23 error web-front@0.5.0 local: `NODE_ENV=local ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js dev --location=local --env=dev --livereload=1`
23 error Exit status 139
24 error Failed at the web-front@0.5.0 local script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 139, true ]
```

Do you have any idea of where this error comes from ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't your mount point and working directory are different for `web-front'

Comment: I mean you're mapping `./web-front to /var/www/web-front` but inside container you're running `npm run local` in `/var/www/twasker-web-front/`

Comment: @SujanAdiga Hum no, sorry it is a copy paste mistake. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of Alpine. Alpine uses musl instead of glibc and this causes problem with some libraries. Use debian or any other distro which uses glibc.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll give it a try as soon as I can an check your answer if it solves my problem